# Wordpress: wp_insert_post fails to add comment_count

Tags: wordpress

I am running the following piece of code (assume all variables have values) is a custom importer that I am trying for Joomla2Wordpress.

```
$ret_id = wp_insert_post(array(
  'ID'   => $pinfo,
  'post_date'  => $Posted,
  'post_date_gmt'  => $post_date_gmt,
  'post_author'  => $authorid,
  'post_modified'  => $LastMod,
  'post_modified_gmt' => $post_modified_gmt,
  'post_title'  => $Title,
  'post_content'  => $Body,
  'post_excerpt'  => $Excerpt,
  'post_status'  => $post_status,
  'post_name'  => $sefurl,
  'comment_count'  => $comments_count)
 );
```

However while the code inserts post correctly, the comments count is not updated (remains zero). The codex page doesn't mention the parameter at all.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I think this may belong on Stack Overflow...

Comment: What's the code used to get to this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_insert_post() does not update the comment count, you have to call **wp_update_comment_count_now()** to update accomplish that.